# auto refresh bootstrap datatable in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**index.php**

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap"
  cellspacing="0" width="100%">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Symbol</th>
      <th>Price USD</th>
      <th>Price BTC</th>
      <th>24h Volume USD</th>
      <th>Market Cap USD</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="dsff">

  </tbody>
</table>

function makeTimer() { jQuery.ajax({ url: "ajax.php", data: { abc: 1}, type: "POST",
success:function(data){ $("#dsff").html(data); }, error:function (){} }); } setInterval(function()
{ makeTimer(); }, 1000); ajax.php

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['abc'])){

                        ?>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>
    <td>fdfdgfdg</a>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <?php  } ?>
```

I am auto-refreshing the table but it is refreshing the complete table.

For example:

- We have pagination I am on the second list only the value should refresh not the complete table.
- Only values should refresh for every 10 seconds.

I have tried this code but didn't work for me:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  ajax: "data.json"
});

setInterval( function () {
  table.ajax.reload();
}, 30000);
```

**Question:** Can anyone please solve this issue?

Comment: post your code, so people can help you.

Comment: "didn't work for me" is not a useful problem description